# Condicionar al select que devuelva el dato del campo o que devuelva NULL

Tags: postgresql

Estoy haciendo una función que retorna una tabla resultado(a int, b int), luego tengo una variable campo_anterior que guarda el valor del campo anterior.
Y lo que necesito es recorrer la tabla(x int, y int, z int), y si campo_actual - campo_anterior > 10, en la columna a debe poner null, caso contrario, se guarda el valor que hay en la columna y dentro de la fila a de la tabla resultado.
Y luego se debe cambiar el valor de campo_anterior con el nuevo anterior.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Podras añadir tu codigo? Asi a texto solo es un poco complejo

Comment: Es que aún no tenía ningún código, pero ya logré resolver

Comment: @JoséCardozo, dado que lo solucionaste deberúas responder tu propia pregunta y compartir la solución con la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente lo que necesitaba era, hacer una comparación de la fila actual con el siguiente, pero el siguiente debe ser también del mismo tipo que el actual, por ejemplo si se tratara de vehiculos como fué mi caso, el siguiente dato debe ser del mismo vehiculo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()

RETURNS TABLE(
    a integer,
    b integer,
)AS $$

DECLARE
    --condicion de diferencia
    condicion  = 10;

BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY(
        SELECT
            --puede agregar otras columnas si se desea
            CASE
                --si la diferencia es mayor que 10 debe devolver null
                WHEN subquery.fila_sgte - subquery.fila_actual >= condicion THEN null
                ELSE subquery.fila_actual
            END AS a,
            b, --otra columna que resulto no importar para lo que no necesitaba
        FROM (
            SELECT *,
                --retornamos la fecha siguiente, y al poner la condición del where, solo retorna el siguiente con el mismo imei
                LEAD(l.fila_actual, 1) OVER(ORDER BY l.fila_actual) fila_sgte,
            FROM localizacion AS l
            WHERE 
                --alguna condicion
            ) as subquery
        order by "fechaGPS" asc
    );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```